# Can I edit the UITableView cell's textLabel directly?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, edit

Ok, I know it seems like there are a bunch of questions on this topic on here already, but I haven't been able to find anything that I need.

I have a UITableViewCell that I want to be able to select (process the touch through `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`) and then respond to that selection by allowing the user to begin editing the contents of the cell's textLabel. I need a label because I need multiple lines of text.
 **I need the height of the cell to grow as the user enters more and more text.**

Do I need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and have my own label or textView I guess? Or can I use the textLabel that is already there?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I may suggest doing, or at the least attempting as your best bet, is to create an array of text strings (NSString) in order for each cell. Of course you know you can edit an array at a specific point, so knowing what cell you selected allows you to know which string to edit. From here when a label text has been edited simply call:
[tableView reloadData]

And it should update that for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how should I allow for the keyboard to come up and the user to edit the textlabel content?

Comment: It depends on how you want to go about your app aesthetically.  Personally I'd throw up a UITextView that takes up the upper half of the screen and the assign it becomeFirstResponder to show the keyboard on the bottom half.  Only make the UITextView visible when you select a cell in your table, and when the "DONE" button is hit on the keyboard have a method to resignFirstResponder and hide your UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution for you, What exactly you need. Even I have faced this problem & found the solution too. Check with this [link](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/08/tableview-with-textfield.html). You need to work more on this example to dynamic sizing the cell

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you should be able to calculate frame of Text using
  NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method.
- In you UITableView delegate implement
  `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Calculate height for
  text in each cell, also include paddings and everything else you
  might need. I would also cache this value until text is changed.
- Subclass UITableViewCell. You have two variants here:

  1. Add UITextView to Cell every time user wants to edit text and remove it back after that.
  2. Use UITextView to display and edit text (it has `editable` property). But I'm not sure how speedy it will be inside table, I haven't tested this personally.

  I use the first variant in my app.
- You can subclass UITextView or use its delegate methods to update its height when user types something.
- Propagate the height change to your UITableView delegate.

Call the following code to update cells animated:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```